# sql query to add a column to select view

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write a select query to view a few columns from a table and add additional columns to it with a default value assigned?

Like `Select a,b,c, d="TIM" from table1;`,
where a,b and c are columns in table1, but "d" isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select a constant value:

```
Select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, 'TIM' as d
from table1 t1;
```

Note that SQL in general -- and Oracle in particular -- uses single quotes to delimit strings.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
select a, b, c, 'TIM' as d
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to fetch the rows from `table1` where `d='TIM'` from another table and the `id`s of these tables are their common fields:

```
SELECT t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t2.d 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.d = 'TIM';
```